# Copy paste variety of bullet point symbol from word to html <textarea> keep bullet signs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

when I copied paste variety of bullets from my .docx document to HTML textarea and I get 'question marks' rather than what we are coping. The remaining part of the text is copying just fine.
[copied bullet from word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewdjj.png)

[when bullet paste into textarea and I get 'question marks' rather than what bullet we are coping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbWVq.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  </head>
<body>
<h1>The textarea element</h1>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
  </textarea>
  <br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix then please help.

Comment: elaborate on the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: What I do to remove formatting is to copy from .docx, paste in Notepad, copy from there and then paste wherever you like.

Comment: @Tr0jAn i add image what bullet are copied from word and what we are getting in textarea when we pasted 'Question marks' https://jsfiddle.net/mayankkrp/og5vuyjp/

Comment: Because a textarea is just text, you should try a WYSIWYG editor for that kind of challenge. Something like [quilljs](https://quilljs.com)  You can try copy-pasting your word documents in the example editor on the page.